# Error when trying to run Node.js on Azure Functions related to gRPC binary module not being found

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, grpc-node

Let's start by saying I have some experience with `Azure Functions` with C# but it's my first time using `Node.js` on `Azure Functions`. 
So, it may be a *newbie question* or may not be a proper question at all.

I've developed several functions (version: *2.x*) with **Node.js** and deployed them as Azure Functions. All of them are working fine locally and on Azure *except* for one who has a dependency on `Firebase`

On my **index.js** file on the corresponding **folder** of my Function I have declared these dependencies:

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed before other Firebase SDKs
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
require("firebase/firestore");
```

Then, on the **package.json** file I have the following `dependencies` (I have pasted only the relevant part):

```
" ": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase": "7.6.1"    
  }
```

This works fine locally. I can run it and debug it *locally* without issues but once I deploy it on Azure I get the following error either if I `run` it manually or with the trigger (in this case a **Timer trigger**):

```
Result: Failure
Exception: Worker was unable to load function NotifySpToUpdateCapacity: 'Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v57-win32-ia32-unknown
Found: [node-v72-win32-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-ia32-unknown\grpc_node.node''
Stack: Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v57-win32-ia32-unknown
Found: [node-v72-win32-x64-unknown]
```

My understanding is that is not being able to find the `gRPC` module. In addition, I understand that it's not being found because it's not in the expected directory but...

how can I fix this? What I need to change or do in order to make it find the proper directory or install the proper dependency?

In addition, I have added to my CI Pipeline a "npm rebuild" as it's suggested on some posts but it seems that it does not solve anything on my current scenario.
I have also tried to change the Node version from ~10 to ~8 but I'm not so sure that I did take effect.
I need some help or if someone can point me into right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally solved my issue. As I stated on the question I'm not familiar with **Node.js** and **npm**.

The specific problem was this:

```
Expected directory: node-v57-win32-ia32-unknown
Found: [node-v72-win32-x64-unknown]
```

I've tried too many things. So, I'll try to put the ones that I believe really made this issue to be sorted out.

Firstly, I have to say that my *local environment* and the *Azure Functions environment* were not the same. So, I made both of them have node version **8.10.0**. 
That solved the *discrepancy* between **node-v57** and **node-v72** that was being found.

I couldn't make the Azure environment be 32 (as the in the error the dependency that was being looked for was 'node-v57-win32-**ia32**-unknown') even if I configured it to be 32.

Then, I realized that my **Azure DevOps Pipeline** could make a difference. I didn't mention that on my original question because I was lost with Node.js and npm stuff and I didn't realize about it.

So, in my pipeline, I firstly put a step to install the same node version.
And finally, what I believe that solved the last bit of the issue was an extra step that performed this:

```
npm rebuild --target=8.10.0 --target_arch=ia32 --update-binary
```

That made the Expected directory: node-v57-win32-ia32-unknown to be found.

I hope this may help someone else struggling with the same kind of issues.